# Can the conduction band minimum of a semiconductor fall above the vacuum level?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is it possible for the conduction band minimum (LUMO) of a semiconductor to be above the vacuum level? If so, what does this physically mean?

Comment: It means you don't have a conduction band.

Comment: One thing to note is that all atoms have multiple un-filled states above the ground state. Coming up with a solid where there are no unoccupied states below the vacuum level is not realistic.